# Android: Cant upload file to firebase using uri generated from listview

Tags: android, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

I have loaded a listView with songs from external memory. I am generating a uri from its position

```
   uri=Uri.parse(songs.get(position).toString());
```

and i use this uri in the putFile(uri) but it is not working. Here is the Upload function

```
    public void UploadFile(Uri uri)
    {
        StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.child("songss/song1.mp3");

        riversRef.putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
```

I have uploaded file using the Intent and that worked perfectly fine but it is not working when i generate the uri from the listview.

Comment: Why do you say it is not working? Do you have an error?

Comment: it gives me this error: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response